# Older line items do not have variant id or product id

Tags: shopify

In my api testing with my development store all line items that were created had a variant id and a product id. Now that our app is in production we are seeing line items from 2012 that do not have a variant id or a product id... Is this to be expected that older line items are not guaranteed to have this information? Is it possible for new line items to also not have this information? This data is integral to identifying a shops products that were sold.

When products are deleted from a store are these values nulled out for associated orders?

Answer (score 0):

You have to develop expecting an order to contain line items that indeed have nil as a variant or product ID. This is due to the POS. Merchants can sell items without a product or variant ID, yet they are valid order line items.

As for it being integral to identifying the shop? How so? Not only can you not get an order via the API without knowing the shop before hand, any webhooks you use also tell you the shop. So knowing the product or variant ID is not logically used to tell you the shop.